# Can I call an external function from another JS script in tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Trying to do this, importing a HTML table into tabulator and creating a table from that.
my code looks like this

```
import get_defense from 'attck_db';
var table = new Tabulator("#mitreattck", {
    layout:"fitTable",
    autoResize:true,
    responsiveLayout:"hide",
    tooltipsHeader:true,
    tooltipGenerationMode:"hover", 
    tooltips:function(cell){
        return get_defense(cell.getValue());
    },
    cellClick:function(e,cell){
        alert(cell.getValue())
    },
});
```

The `get_defense` function is in another js that I am importing in another <script> tag.
If I even use the `get_defense` call the table fails to build. Any pointers ?

Comment: What is the error? Can you call get_defense(some_value) outside the table?

Comment: Without seeing how you have imported the file containing the `get_defence` file it is hard to offer advice. It is likely a scope issue